# Dynamic call into view model

Tags: c#, viewmodel

I am using view models inside of other view models to create a complex form.  This particular form has 3 different contacts on it and I would like to dynamically call the particular contact. Below is an example of the 3 different contact type fields for the last name.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Projects[0].SponsorContact.LastName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Projects[0].BrokerContact.LastName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Projects[0].LogisticsContact.LastName)
```

I would think there must be some way to have a string with value "SponsorContact" or "BrokerContact" which could be used for the call.

Comment: When you say "have a string with value" are you talking about using an indexer like this?  m.Projects["SponsorContact"]?  Please clarify.

Comment: Something like that but if I could be specific at that level I would have the answer.  From you question I take it you also program in PHP where such is very simple.

Comment: A little but I handle mostly C#.  If you are referring to an associative array, C# doesn't have the same thing.  The closest you will get is a Dictionary of key value pairs.  But even then I don't know if it is really going to save you that much.  As far as I know you are doing it the way it will have to be done.  Although, instead of using Projects[0] this way, you could use a @foreach statement and loop through all the projects instead of having to call out each index individually.

Comment: Agreed, "used for the call" is not clear.  Call to TextBoxFor?  If so, how would a string "SponsorContact" be used for that?

Comment: It isn't about saving time, more about elegance of code. The contact portions of the form need to switch partial view via ajax depending on the selected country. There are 3 contact sections, but I only need one to load that has had its country select box change. I am beginning to suspect that C# is going to make me code 3 copies of the contact form in each partial view with an if statement based on contact type to get the correct form field names.    I just didn't think all the background of why I needed it was helpful to the question.